# Why doesn't Beautifulsoup return the required items from this page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im following the tutorials, but whatever i ask for, like menuitem = page_soup.findAll("h5")
it keeps returning nothing, but i know they exist, i can see them, yet it finds nothing
im doing exactly as the tutorials do yet it keeps saying there's nothing, im trying to pull from a plant site and find the name of the plant in my language which is displayed and visible on the page
example:  https://identify.plantnet.org/observation/weurope/1007256673

im trying to get a single word from that page and it seems impossible as the soup keeps saying things don't exist when they do
help is appreciated

Comment: please post the code you are using

Comment: In order to help with this, it would be helpful if you posted the code you're using up to the point where you're calling findAll(). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/28106 for instructions.

Comment: you should also take a look at the "page source" that you are using as a "soup" with the `print(soup.prettify())` command

Comment: import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

determination_url = "https://identify.plantnet.org/observation/weurope/1007256673"

page_list = req(determination_url)
page_info = page_list.read()
page_list.close()
soup_page = soup(page_info, "html.parser")

containers = soup_page.findAll("a")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically from their API in Json format, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. But you can use `requests` module to load it:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://identify.plantnet.org/observation/weurope/1007256673'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
api_url = 'https://api.plantnet.org/v1/projects/weurope/observations/{plant_id}?lang=en'
plant_id = url.split('/')[-1]

data = requests.get(api_url.format(plant_id=plant_id), headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
print('{} - {}'.format(data['submittedName'], data['species']['commonNames'][0]))
```

Prints:

```
Solanum dulcamara L. - Bittersweet
```

Comment: I totally forgot  to thank you, this worked excactly how i wanted it to, i'm very thankfull, i managed to use this perfectly to make what i was trying to make. I just have one more question, how did you get to that api page where ur pulling the info from, like if i wanna do this with a site, how do i figure out where to find that link
in this case: https://api.plantnet.org/v1/projects/weurope/observations/{plant_id}?lang=en'
but where did you find this link and how would i find a link like this if i wanted to repeat this process with another website, thanks :)

Comment: @user13281317 I observed the API page through Firefox developer tools (Network tab). In Chrome exists something similar too. There are all requests made by the page, including Ajax calls as well.